# AWS CodeBuild - How to use one and the same buildspec.yml for multiple projects?

Tags: aws-codebuild

We have the following GitHub projects setting (Maven, Java):

Project000
Project001
..

They should use exactly the same buildspec.yml and we do not place it in every object. However, in CodeBuild we should copy/paste directly in the project build or have it as a file in all the projects. Is there a way to point to a single file i.e called buildspec.yml and stored in S3?

Answer (score 2):

Hello Stanislav Ivanov,

AWSCodeBuild just came out with a new feature where you can override everything in a project. Using this feature you could have 1 base project which includes your buildspec, then override the source depending on what you would like to build.

Let me know if that helps,
John

Comment: Thank you very much John (@creeper123)! Can you please add a link to the documentation with more explanation how we can do that?

Comment: Please link the feature you are referring to.